# How to use a while loop to make code continue?

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry, I tried researching about while loops and the examples that I found didn't help me very much. I am having a hard time understanding the concept outside of peoples examples. I am new to python and most tutorials use a while loop in a different scenario. So here is my code:

```
# This is a guess the number game.
import random

# Ask the user what their name is
print ('Hello. What is your name?')
name = input ()

# Ask the user if they would like to play a game.
# If user confirms, game continues
# If user denies, game ends
print ('Hi ' + name + ' It is nice to meet you.')
print ('Would you like to play a game with me?')

answer = input()
confirm = ['Yes', 'yes',' Y', 'y', 'Yea', 'yea', 'Yeah', 'yeah', 'Yup',  'yup']
deny = ['No', 'no', 'N', 'n', 'Nope', 'nope', 'Nah', 'nah']

if answer in confirm:
  print ('Great! Let\'s get started!')
elif answer in deny:
  print ('I am sorry to hear that. Maybe next time? Goodbye') + exit()

print ('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')


print ('Can you guess what the number is?') 

secretNumber = random.randint (1, 20)
print('DEBUG: The secret number is ' + str(secretNumber)) # DEBUG

for guessesTaken in range (1, 7):
  print ('Take a guess.')
  guess = int(input())

  if guess < secretNumber:
    print ('Your guess is to low.')
  elif guess > secretNumber:
    print ('Your guess is to high!')
  else:
    break # This condition is for the correct guess!

if guess == secretNumber:
  print ('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed the number in ' +       str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses.')
else:
  print ('Wrong. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))

print ('Would you like to play again?')
play_again = input()

if play_again in confirm:
    print('# Put code to make game restart') 
elif play_again in deny:
    print ('Thanks for playing!')

exit()
```

I would like to use a while loop (because I think thats what I need, please enlighten me if not) at the "if play_again in confirm:" statement to make it return back to the "I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20" line. That way a user can continue to play the game if they choose.

Thankyou in advance. I am also using newest Python.

Comment: Please introduce the code before posting it :) There is also a lot of redundant code that can be shortened such as the inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code with `while` loop added:

```
# This is a guess the number game.
import random

# Ask the user what their name is
print ('Hello. What is your name?')
name = input ()

# Ask the user if they would like to play a game.
# If user confirms, game continues
# If user denies, game ends
print ('Hi ' + name + ' It is nice to meet you.')
print ('Would you like to play a game with me?')

answer = input()
confirm = ['Yes', 'yes',' Y', 'y', 'Yea', 'yea', 'Yeah', 'yeah', 'Yup',  'yup']
deny = ['No', 'no', 'N', 'n', 'Nope', 'nope', 'Nah', 'nah']

if answer in confirm:
  print ('Great! Let\'s get started!')
elif answer in deny:
  print ('I am sorry to hear that. Maybe next time? Goodbye') + exit()

while True:

  print ('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')


  print ('Can you guess what the number is?') 

  secretNumber = random.randint (1, 20)
  print('DEBUG: The secret number is ' + str(secretNumber)) # DEBUG

  for guessesTaken in range (1, 7):
    print ('Take a guess.')
    guess = int(input())

    if guess < secretNumber:
      print ('Your guess is to low.')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
      print ('Your guess is to high!')
    else:
      break # This condition is for the correct guess!

  if guess == secretNumber:
    print ('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed the number in ' +       str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses.')
  else:
    print ('Wrong. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))

  print ('Would you like to play again?')
  play_again = input()

  if play_again in confirm:
    #print('# Put code to make game restart') 
    continue
  elif play_again in deny:
    print ('Thanks for playing!')
    break

exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of what you are trying to do, using a while loop.

```
import random as rand
target = rand.randint(1,100)

found = False
while not found:
    print ("***Random Number Guess***")
    guess = int(input("What is your guess?"))
    if guess == target:
        print("Good guess, you found it!")
        repeat = input("Play again? y/n")
        if repeat == 'n':
            found = True
        elif repeat == 'y':
            target = rand.randint(1,100)
            found = False
    else:
        if guess < target:
            print("too low")
        else:
            print("too high")
```